# How to reference a variable of the component in a function not called in angular2/4?

Tags: angular, variables, ztree

I am using [ztree](http://www.treejs.cn/v3/api.php) in my component, there is a function named `addHoverDom(treeId, treeNode)`, it's defined in the component, but it doesn't get called in the way that angular usually does. Below is the function:

```
 addHoverDom(treeId, treeNode) {
    let aObj = $("#" + treeNode.tId + "_a");
    let addBtnId = "diy_add_" + treeNode.tId;
    let ztree = $.fn.zTree.getZTreeObj(treeId);
    if ($("#" + addBtnId).length == 0) {
      $("#" + addBtnId).bind("click", function() {
        //reference a variable of the component here
      });
    }
}
```

and this is how it called:

```
setting: Object = {
  callback: {
    onClick: this.zTreeOnClick
  },
  view: {
    addHoverDom: this.addHoverDom,
    removeHoverDom: this.removeHoverDom
  }
};
```

Now I want to get a variable of the component in the function, I tried the component `name.prototype` and renamed this to that, but neither worked, can anyone help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is function `addHoverDom` defined in your  component which you want to reference?

Comment: In the component, it's a funciton of ztree, it can be customized.

Comment: Yes, it's in the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume function `addHoverDom` is defined in the component where you want to refer to, you can use **arrow function** to keep the context and use `this` directly in function `addHoverDom` to refer component's field, refer below example:

```
addHoverDom(treeId, treeNode) {
  ...
  if ($("#" + addBtnId).length == 0) {
    $("#" + addBtnId).bind("click", () => {       // use arrow function to keep context
      //reference a variable of the component here
      // example code
      this.variable_name = 'test';
      const test = this.variable_name;      
    });
  }
}
```

Also you may need to keep context for callback of `addHoverDom`

```
setting: Object = {
  callback: {
    onClick: this.zTreeOnClick
  },
  view: {
    addHoverDom: this.addHoverDom.bind(this),     // bind this to keep the context
    removeHoverDom: this.removeHoverDom
  }
};
```

Comment: That's it, but bind this is necessary, thanks a lot.

Comment: @HalShaw You are welcome! Also thanks for the feed back.